# Using CTE for a child with multiple parents

Tags: sql-server

I have a CTE already implemented for organizations with one to one relation. Now I have to allow having one child with multiple parents.

I have a table **OrgRelation**, as you can see I added on the table **OrgC** now having another parent **OrgD**

```
Child   Parent
OrgA    NULL
OrgB    OrgA
OrgC    OrgB
OrgC    OrgD
```

The table above represents this tree view:

```
OrgA        
    OrgB    
        OrgC
    OrgD    
        OrgC
```

How to construct the CTE query? it has a different with the normal CTE?

```
WITH CTE AS   
(  
    SELECT Parent, Child, 0 AS Level
    FROM dbo.OrgRelation
    WHERE Parent IS NULL  
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT e.Parent, e.Child, Level + 1  
    FROM dbo.OrgRelation AS e  
        INNER JOIN CTE AS d  
        ON e.Parent = d.Child
)  
SELECT Parent, Child, Level   
FROM CTE;
```

Besides, if I go from bottom to top I should get two different structure, one from OrgD and the other from OrgB right?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  What is the expected ouptut?

Comment: Basically what I need is to sending an specific organization, it will return all organizations below, what I'm not sure is the impact of having now multiple parents for the same organization

Comment: Based on the tree view, it appears OrgD is a child of OrgA.  If this is the true,  you need another row in OrgRelation showing that relationship.  If you add that row, OrgD will show up in your current CTE query.